# IIS7 - Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config

I know this is an old question and asked many times before. But believe me I've tried them all and found no resolution.

And my web.config looks like :-

```
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="512000" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Uploading a file of around 72 MB is popping up me this error - "Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value."

PS:- Using IIS7.

Comment: You sure it's not a setting on the upload control or in code for the control? Sounds like the server but just checking.

Comment: upload control only checks for file type (doc,pdf etc). I can upload file upto 4mb. I guess it's a server issue.

Comment: You see the `maxRequestLength` a few lines above? Maybe adjust that. Just a guess.

Comment: maxAllowedContentLength is specified in bytes (maxRequestLength is in KB).  Try throwing a few more zeros on maxAllowedContentLength

Comment: it's already 500 mb i guess. will add some 0 now.

Comment: 75 MB is about 75.5 million bytes. maxAllowedContentLength *is* too low.